# la palabra clave contextual 'var' solo puede hacer dentro de una declaracion de variable local o en codigo script

Tags: c#

tengo un error al crear la variable matriz:

En visual basic lo tengo asi:
**`Dim matriz(cantidad_alumnos, cantidad_notas)`**

En c# asi:
**`var[,] matriz = new var[cantidad_alumnos + 1, cantidad_notas + 1];`**
aqui mismo es donde tengo el error. Como podria definirla a la misma?

Comment: que vas a guardar en esa matriz? var se usa para inferir el tipo de variable.. no es un tipo de variable...

Comment: voy a guardar datos de tipo ushort

Comment: En C# no existe la palabra clave `var`, debe quedar de la siguiente forma `ushort[,] matriz = new ushort[cantidad_alumnos + 1, cantidad_notas + 1]`.

Comment: @EduardoReyes la palabra clave var en c# si existe y es muy usada, para matriz no se usa, pero para crear genericos o primitivos si se puede usar.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Gracias por sacarme de ese error, cierto es que aunque uso Visual Studio 2017, solo tengo la colección MSDN de Visual Studio 2005 y en aquella versión C# solo tenia en sus Contextual Keywords 6 palabras claves. Ahora se que C# 3, ya incluyó la palabra clave `var`, te agradezco por incitarme a investigar sobre el tema; aunque creo que no me gustaría usar variables de "tipo" implícito, pues aunque el compilador determina el tipo adecuado, no creo que lo haga así el editor de código y las facilidades de IntelliSense y otras que brinda, no se podrían aprovechar.

Comment: @EduardoReyes no solo el compilador lo infiere.. tambien lo infiere la IDE y tenes intellisense, debug y todo lo mismo que con cualquier otro tipo de variable....

Answer (score 1):

No puedes usar var para crear un arreglo, debes definir un tipo de dato.

```
int[,] matriz = new int[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
long[,] matriz = new long[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
string[,] matriz = new string[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
decimal[,] matriz = new decimal[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
MiObjeto[,] matriz = new MiObjeto[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
```

Debes tener claro primero que tipo de dato quieres guardar en la matriz.

Al usar var se espera asumir el tipo al momento de la asignación, como no se puede inferir el tipo de dato, no te va a dejar crearlo.
También puedes crear el arreglo de la siguiente manera.

```
var matriz = new int[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
var matriz = new long[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
var matriz = new string[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
var matriz = new decimal[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
var matriz = new MiObjeto[cant_alumnos,can_notas];
```

En el ultimo ejemplo no te arrojara error, ya que el tipo de dato se esta asumiendo al instanciar.